# pip install Django hangs

Tags: python, django, pip

Recently I have been unable to install Django 1.10 (or earlier version) using `pip install django` inside or outside a virtual enviornment.

After running the command pip hangs on the line 'Collecting Django' and does nothing. I ran the command in verbose (-vvvvv) mode and get this:

`Collecting django
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
  "GET /simple/django/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12273`

Then it just hangs without an error message.

The only way I can install Django is running pip with `sudo`, but I want to install it inside a virtual environment, not globally.

I can install other packages without any problem. I am on OS X El Capitan.

Comment: Make sure your virtualenv is activated. (if you don't have permission you will get an error. ) Maybe your internet connection isn't good.

Comment: It's definitely activated and I've tried on two different connections which are working normally, thanks though.